# Correctnes of showing the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

at the moment I am  trying to show the convergence of the following series.
The start ist okay for me, but then I got stuck or better, I am not sure if its right:
The series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}} $ with $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

My solution using the ratio test:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| =  \left| \frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}} \right| = \left| \frac{x^{n+1}\;\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\;x^n} \right| \\
= \left| \frac{x\;\sqrt{n}} {\sqrt{1+n}} \right| = \left|x\;\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \right| = |x| \; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n(1+\frac{1}{n})} = |x|
$$
And if $|x|<1$ the series converges, otherwise it diverges.

**Question** Are my last steps correct?

Regards,
Christoph

Comment: You need to test the points $x=1$ and $x=-1$ separately. The Ratio test only tells you the series diverges for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is correct but your conclusion is wrong. In fact we conclude that $1$ is the radius of convergence but notice that the interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$.

Comment: I see it, if $x=-1$ then the Leibnitz criteria applies, and for $x=1$ I can see that it's monotonic decreasing to 0.

Comment: For $x=1$ the series is divergent since it's a Riemann divergent series $\alpha=\frac12<1$.

Comment: Oh, I just didn't see the x^k. I just read in my script, that I have to find a divergent minorante to compare it, I will check my notices.

Answer (score 2):

All correct except for one point: if $x=-1$ the series converges.